# Permute package in R

Tags: r, package, permutation

I came across the package `Permute` from StackOverflow forum. I am trying to perform permutations as part of my project. I was trying to use `mt.sample.rawp()` from package `multtest`. But there are some specifications I require which I am unable to do with the aformentioned function. I would like to know if I could use your package for it. I will explain my problem. I am new to R so apologies if my R cmd knowledge is weak.

I have a dataset and I want to perform permutations on class labels (CL) and compute **raw p-value.** I have **my own t-test which is a modified t-test** needed for my project. I should be able to perform **permutation using this modified t-test** of mine.

Also, this is a little similar to one of the questions you had solved using your package. I have 2 class labels, but when I permute, I have an index value for each sample in my data and the permutation hence should not be done for each row in the data but permute Class label (CL) for each index in the data.

An eg of my data:

```
Sample  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
Index   1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 
CL      0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

I am unable to show it in matrix format here. Each heading is a column in my dataset. Any snippets or reference codes I could use. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Me it would appear. I'm busy with the day job just now, but I'll come back and think about an Answer later today or tomorrow (UK time) if someone doesn't do so before me.

Answer (score 2):

```
require(permute) ## load package

## data
dat <- data.frame(Sample = 1:8, Index = rep(1:4, each = 2),
                  CL = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0))
```

Now we need a control object that defines how the permutations should be stratified. For that use `permControl()`:

```
> ctrl <- with(dat, permControl(strata = Index))
> ctrl

No. of permutations: 199  

**** STRATA ****
Permutations are stratified within: Index 
Strata unpermuted

**** SAMPLES ****
Permutation type: free 
Mirrored permutations for Samples?: No 
Use same permutation within strata?: No
```

Next we generate permutations, here I produce a set of 10 permutations of the row indices

```
> set.seed(10)
> perms <- shuffleSet(nrow(dat), nset = 10, control = ctrl)
> perms
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    2    1    3    4    5    6    7    8
 [2,]    2    1    4    3    5    6    7    8
 [3,]    1    2    3    4    6    5    8    7
 [4,]    1    2    4    3    6    5    8    7
 [5,]    1    2    3    4    6    5    8    7
 [6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
 [7,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
 [8,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
 [9,]    2    1    4    3    5    6    7    8
[10,]    2    1    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

The rows of `perms` are the permutations and the columns refer to the rows of the original data.

If you just want a single permutation at a time, such as when you are using a loop to do your permutation test, then use `shuffle()` instead of `shuffleSet()`, e.g.:

```
> set.seed(10)
> perm <- shuffle(nrow(dat), control = ctrl)
> perm
[1] 2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

To use the shuffle set of `perms`, just index into `dat`:

```
> dat[perms[1, ], ]
  Sample Index CL
1      1     1  0
2      2     1  0
4      4     2  1
3      3     2  1
5      5     3  1
6      6     3  1
8      8     4  0
7      7     4  0
> dat[perms[2, ], ]
  Sample Index CL
1      1     1  0
2      2     1  0
3      3     2  1
4      4     2  1
5      5     3  1
6      6     3  1
7      7     4  0
8      8     4  0
> dat[perms[3, ], ]
  Sample Index CL
2      2     1  0
1      1     1  0
3      3     2  1
4      4     2  1
6      6     3  1
5      5     3  1
7      7     4  0
8      8     4  0
```

Comment: @Andrie- Thanks a lot for helping me get the data in matrix form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me with the package. It samples the rows of sample without changing the Index pre-assigned to the samples. But with this ctrl, I should be able to permute the class labels for the samples. Basically breaking the relation between the samples and class labels.

Comment: You asked to "... the permutation hence should not be done for each row in the data but permute Class label (CL) for each index in the data". I took that to mean that you wanted to permute the Class labels (`CL`) within the levels of `Index`. If you want something different, perhaps you could explain?

Comment: Hi Gavin, I think I will tell you what the title mean here so that I can be more clear with my doubt. The index is the biological replicates of a sample, and the number of indexes for each sample depends on the number of time points. So if a sample has 3 observations it has been studied over 3 time points. So when I permute the condition 1 and condition 2 (0 and 1 here), the samples should be permuted between 0 and 1 but the set of samples with index 1, should be taken together as one value and then assign the new CL to all the observations with that index value. Am I any clearer? :)